# Flask-admin: How to change foreign key and update related records

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-admin

I have two tables with a foreign key relationship and I am using flask-admin as admin GUI.

In some cases I need to modify the foreign-key. In this case all existing Records of the related table should be updated (with new foreign key). How would you implement this functionality?

I tried the on_model_change function of flask-admin. Although I run into the problem, that I only get the updated key from the function(?) -> (I need the old key to find the existing assessment-records and update them). Additionally I'm not able to commit the new key unless the Assessment records have been updated (foreign key constraint would not be met).

Can I achieve this functionality within the flask-admin GUI?

```
class Assessment(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "assesment_table"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
psr_id = db.Column(db.String(40), db.ForeignKey("psr_object_table.psr_id"))

class Unit(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "units_table"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(80))
psr_id = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)


#needed for Flask-Admin view 
class UnitView(ModelView):
    def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):
        #get old_key
        #query and update db with new foreign key
        #commit everything
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use database side cascades:

```
class Assessment(db.Model):
    ...
    psr_id = db.Column(db.String(40), db.ForeignKey("psr_object_table.psr_id",
                                                    onupdate="CASCADE"))
```